# Is it possible to mix several requests in only one?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I already asked this question, but nobody answered. I'm gonna ask it again since I'm pretty sure the problem is easily solvable by someone who knows more than me (I know nothing) in Django. I have a search tool. When I use it, it searches through my five Django models, thus sends five GET requests to my REST API. The annoying thing is that it displays five requests in my console. Is there any way to "mix" these five requests and only display it as a single request ? Or, is there any way to do a single request on several models ? Teach me, please.

Edit : example of one of my view doing the query :

```
class ProjectList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer #My serializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Project.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        query = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('query', None)
        # Perf enhancements :
        queryset = queryset.prefetch_related('user', 'tasks')
        # ---
        if query is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(name__icontains=query) |
                Q(created_on__icontains=query)).order_by('name')

        return queryset

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.user = self.request.user #This links the project to an user
                            #Don't think it's useful here but anyway
```

And I have four more views doing queries, one per model. They're all like this one so I don't think it's important to post them.

These queries are made in my javascript file (I'm using angularjs) like this :

```
this.doSearch = function(query) {
    if (query.length > 2) {
        this.searchengine.projects = $resource('/api/projects').get({query: query});
        this.searchengine.tasks = $resource('/api/tasks').get({query: query});
        this.searchengine.comments = $resource('/api/comments').get({query: query});
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't re-ask questions here. To draw more attentions you can [put a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) on it.

Comment: It's a duplicate indeed, since I said in my post I was reposting the question. Any way to "bump" the one you linked and hope for someone to answer it ?

Comment: All right thanks @gertvdijk ! But... I only have one reputation. What do ?

Comment: Please add parts of your code here. Like the django view which gets called and sends requests to your rest api.

Comment: @Roflnaut Invest some time in the site and you'll gain more reputation to be able to set bounties. In the meantime you can edit your original question to include more details. Work on it. Make it awesome. ;) Oh, and please **edit** your comments if you have something to add instead of posting individual ones.

Comment: I'm editing, give me two minutes. Edit : @gertvdijk all right sorry I'm new here

Comment: Rather than try to compress the logging of requests after they've been called (and arguably compromise the integrity of the log in the process), why not create a new resource endpoint that composts the 2 queries server-side?  That will almost certainly be more efficient anyway.  The Django docs say that the serializers will work on any iterable that yields model objects, so you should be able to do all your queries then just return an `itertools.chain` that chains all your query results together.  If you need to structure things more, you might need to adjust your serializer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new endpoint for search which returns multiple types of objects:

```
class SearchView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        data = []

        queryset = Project.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        query = self.request.QUERY_PARAMS.get('query', None)
        queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(name__icontains=query) |
                Q(created_on__icontains=query)).order_by('name')
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        data.extend(serializer.data)
        #do the same for other types of objects

        return Response(data)
```